# Cannot find interface declaration for superclass of

Tags: objective-c

I know this is a common subject but I did not find any answer to help me out with this problem.

Well, I do have (by now) 3 .h files, 
One is the superclass of the two others.

Superclass : ExportationAutoFilterNew

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <HIDDEN/PluginFilter.h>

@class MyOutlineView;

@interface ExportationAutoFilterNew : PluginFilter
    @property (assign, nonatomic) NSUserDefaults *prefs;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) MyOutlineView *databaseOutline;
@end
```

Then, sub-classes : DetectNewExams & ExportExams

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <HIDDEN/PluginFilter.h>
#import "ExportationAutoFilterNew.h"

@interface DetectNewExams : ExportationAutoFilterNew

- (void)detectExams:(NSDate*)currentDate timeInterval:(double)timeInterval afterExitHidden:(BOOL)check;
```

And

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <HIDDEN/PluginFilter.h>
#import "ExportationAutoFilterNew.h"

@interface ExportExams : ExportationAutoFilterNew

- (void)exportExams:(NSManagedObject*)curObj;
```

The .m goes like this

Superclass : ExportationAutoFilter

```
#import <HIDDEN/PreferencesWindowController.h>
#import <HIDDEN/browserController.h>
#import "ExportationAutoFilterNew.h"
#import "DetectNewExams.h"

@implementation ExportationAutoFilterNew
```

Xcode for this file (ExportationAutoFilterNew.m) :

```
Instance method '-detectExams:timeInterval:afterExitHidden:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

For the call of :

```
[self detectExams:lastExportDate timeInterval:0 afterExitHidden:YES];
```

Sub-classes : DetectNewExams

```
#import <HIDDEN/PreferencesWindowController.h>
#import <HIDDEN/browserController.h>
#import "DetectNewExams.h"
#import "ExportExams.h"

@implementation DetectNewExams
```

In this file (DetectNewExams.m), Xcode says :

```
Instance method '-exportExams:' not found(return type defaults to 'id')
```

Calling :

```
[self exportExams:curObj];
```

And then :  ExportExams

```
#import <HIDDEN/PreferencesWindowController.h>
#import <HIDDEN/browserController.h>
#import "ExportExams.h"

@implementation ExportExams
```

I'm wasting hours on this thing and I can't figure the problem out, may you help me ? I looked up for compiling circle but I don't think I created one with my imports ..

Thanks.

Comment: Class names should always start with capital letters.

Comment: What file is Xcode compiling when it spews that error message?

Comment: detectNewExams.h and exportExams.h

Comment: Xcode doesn't compile header files.  Post the actual error message in its entirety.

Comment: I changed my class name and I do have some warnings by now, but the errors seems to be gone.

Comment: My post has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is not properly declared. Try this.

```
@interface ExportationAutoFilterNew : PluginFilter
    @property (nonatomic) NSUserDefaults *prefs;
    @property (nonatomic) MyOutlineView *databaseOutline;
@end
```

Comment: I posted them ? Every of my interfaces are implemented

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread because it said you only had two implementation file

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have posted the actual error, this becomes more clear.  But you still haven't posted enough context.

`Instance method '-detectExams:timeInterval:afterExitHidden:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

That means that the method declaration hasn't been seen at the time the code was compiled or the method is declared on some class that whatever was being called is not an instance of.

Since you haven't shown the call site or the declaration of the variable being called, this is a guess.   The method is declared on the `DetectNewExams` class.  I'd bet you have a variable that points to an instance of `ExportationAutoFilterNew` and, therefore, the compiler is correctly warning that the method doesn't exist on the class.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to make it as clear as possible but since I just discovered POO, this is a bit hard for me. I added the call of the method where Xcode gets angry. Hope it's enough..